# Are there rules for creating magic items that can be activated with a swift action?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

The mighty [Magic Item Creation Rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html).

I'm looking to create a custom Wondrous Item. All the applicable cost schemes are either for standard action activation or continuous. I'd like to have activation take a swift action (although an immediate action or free action would be nice too).

Are there any published rules for creating such an item? What are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Only indirectly are rules provided for creating an item that takes a swift action to  activate

The section [Creating Magic Items](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) says

> Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal.

Thus, by incorporating a spell modified by the metamagic feat [Quicken Spell](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#quicken-spell) into the creation of a custom magic item (therefore substantially increasing one or more prerequisite spells' effective levels therefore the item's market price), the item could possibly be activated as a swift action. Like all custom magic items, however, *actually* creating such an item hinges upon the GM, but this is, at least, a starting point for negotiations.

Examples of existing items that have as a creation prerequisite the feat Quicken Spell include the [*spell totem*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/spell-to), which is like a [*minor ring of spell storing*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-spell-storing-minor) except that the wearer can take a swift action to use a stored spell when the wearer assumes animal form, and (with a different kind of activation time yet a similar and interesting effect) the [*ring of vengeful blood magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-vengeful-blood-magic), which allows a [bloodraging](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager#TOC-Bloodrage-Su-) wearer thrice per day to cast as an attack of opportunity a 3rd-level-or-less casting-time-of-1-standard-action-or-less spell.

(Many magic items take a swift action to activate without needing the feat Quicken Spell as a creation prerequisite. However, no guidelines exist for creating these besides, as always, comparing them to existing items.)

Answer (score -4):

It depends on the creation and the magic spell that is being imbued into the item. As described from below from [Pazio](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems.html).

> To use a magic item, it must be activated, although sometimes activation simply means putting a ring on your finger. Some items, once donned, function constantly. In most cases, though, using an item requires a standard action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity. By contrast, spell completion items are treated like spells in combat and do provoke attacks of opportunity. 
>   Activating a magic item is a standard action unless the item description indicates otherwise. However, the casting time of a spell is the time required to activate the same power in an item, regardless of the type of magic item, unless the item description specifically states otherwise.

Now this says that most activations will be of a standard action. However certain items that say otherwise (and will be noted within the items stats) will/can be used as that given action (weather it be free/swift/movement).

And the hyper link is as follows if you wish to look further into it. As it will go thru each of the [four magic item activations.](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems.html).

Comment: While this answer is now on topic, it doesn't convey any useful or new information. Also, my question is very clear that I am trying to create a magic item with swift action activation time. Independent of the spell stored within, I can't find any rules about it, hence my question asking for them.

Comment: And as i have clearly commented. It is decided by the spells within the item. And i will spell it out even better for you. You have to look at each item and its spells. Then you have to find the spells with swift activation. And then you have to put said spell with quick activation into the item.

Comment: The question isn't asking about that, it's asking about making an arbitrary item that uses swift instead of standard actions.

Comment: I'd like to have activation take a swift action (although an immediate action or free action would be nice too). Is the question. So as i said you have to find a spell that uses this and see if the gm is willing to allow the same swift action from the activatable item to a created one. As for an arbitrary item taking a swift action that is another question way off base

Comment: To the contrary, it is not way off base, it is exactly what this question is about. You are welcome to ignore that, but in that case you'll just have to live with being downvoted.

Comment: Which i already was